# Issue while migrating from swift 2.3 to swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

I've updated my code from swift 2.3 to swift 3 & got many errors removed all of them but got stuck here

I am getting error at  didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath of UITableView

Task: I hit API for data and populate data in tableview which works properly but I want to save data on didselectrowatindexpath this all was working for me in swift2.3

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    print("selected ")
    //print(self.searchflightsandfares[indexPath.row] as SearchFlightsAndFares)

    let data: NSData
   // data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self.searchflightsandfares[indexPath.row].airlineCodeOneWay)

    data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self.searchflightsandfares[indexPath.row]) as SearchFlightsAndFares


    //Set Data
    UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "selectedFlightDetailData")

    SelectedFlightDetailsVC()
}
```

Error Is
[image]

Model Class is:

```
    import UIKit
import Foundation

class SearchFlightsAndFares:NSObject{

    //segment data
    var segmentaDataForDetailScreen:[NSDictionary]
    var fareDataFromFlight:Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

    //Flight Details -One Way
    var airlineCodeOneWay:      String? //for list view
    var airlineNameOneWay:      String? //for list view
    var airlineCodeOneWaySegment:String? //for Detail view
    var airlineNameOneWaySegment:String? //for Detail view
….more code …
init(fareDataFromFlight:            Dictionary<String, AnyObject>,
         segmentaDataForDetailScreen:   [NSDictionary],
         airlineCodeOneWay:             String, //for list view
         airlineNameOneWay:             String, //for list view
         airlineCodeOneWaySegment:      String, //Flight Number one way
         airlineNameOneWaySegment:      String,

….more code …
{


        self.fareDataFromFlight             = fareDataFromFlight
        self.segmentaDataForDetailScreen    = segmentaDataForDetailScreen
        //One Way
        self.airlineCodeOneWay              = airlineCodeOneWay
        self.airlineNameOneWay              = airlineNameOneWay
        self.airlineCodeOneWaySegment       = airlineCodeOneWaySegment
}

init(espDictionary: [String : AnyObject])
    {

    logic for assignment from API to InIt Variables //….more code …
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.fareDataFromFlight                   = (aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "fareDataFromFlight") as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)!
        self.segmentaDataForDetailScreen          = (aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "segmentaDataForDetailScreen") as? [NSDictionary])!
        //One Way
        self.airlineCodeOneWay          = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "airlineCodeOneWay") as? String
        self.airlineNameOneWay          = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "airlineNameOneWay") as? String
        self.airlineCodeOneWaySegment   = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "airlineCodeOneWaySegment") as? String
        self.airlineNameOneWaySegment   = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "airlineNameOneWaySegment") as? String

….more code …

}


func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {


        aCoder.encode(self.fareDataFromFlight,                  forKey: "fareDataFromFlight")
        aCoder.encode(self.segmentaDataForDetailScreen,         forKey: "segmentaDataForDetailScreen")

        //One way
        aCoder.encode(self.airlineCodeOneWay,         forKey: "airlineCodeOneWay")
        aCoder.encode(self.airlineNameOneWay,         forKey: "airlineNameOneWay")
        aCoder.encode(self.airlineCodeOneWaySegment,  forKey: "airlineCodeOneWaySegment")
        aCoder.encode(self.airlineNameOneWaySegment,  forKey: "airlineNameOneWaySegment")

….more code …

}
```

Comment: add deceleration code of array self.searchflightsandfares

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aaaah Finally I got It In swift 3.0 this function`func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {}` changed to `func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder)` got a refrence at [Solution for this](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/12/3/fixing-project-10-nscoding) thanks for your time and help @vadian

Answer (score 1):

No need for the extra declaration line. This is not Objective-C. Comment it out.

```
// let data: Data
```

The item in the array is supposed to be casted rather than the archived object. So put the closing parenthesis to the end.

```
let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self.searchflightsandfares[indexPath.row] as SearchFlightsAndFares)
```

If you declare the data source array to a concrete Swift type (`[SearchFlightsAndFares]`) you don't need to cast anything.

Comment: I tried it many ways tried the way suggested by @jignesh also all this code was working on swift 2.3 I don't know why it's not working here, I am getting this error in logs, If I replace it with your suggested code '[projectName.SearchFlightsAndFares encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9f20033800'

Comment: You should add the `NSCoding` adoption in the custom class.

Comment: already have `required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) ` and  `func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder)` in nsobject class. Is that you are asking me to do..... I have no idea about which custom class I have to do this apart from this I have only one other class i.e. `SearchFlightsAndFaresCellTableViewCell:UITableViewCell` with `var searchFlightsAndFares: SearchFlightsAndFares! {
        didSet {
            self.updateUI()
        }
    }`  to update data from model class i.e. SearchFlightsAndFares

Comment: No, I mean `NSCoding` after `NSObject`

Answer (score 0):

if your searchflightsandfares array  type is

```
let searchflightsandfares = [SearchFlightsAndFares]()
```

then you need to write this

```
data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: searchflightsandfares[indexPath.row]) as NSData
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: I have that After class Sorry I haven't wrote it `var searchflightsandfares = [SearchFlightsAndFares]()`